# setting decimal places to a float value

Tags: java, number-formatting

```
float a= (float) 1846.4;

NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

float b = Float.parseFloat( df.format(a));
```

What would be the best way to set decimal places for a float (I just want to set 2 decimal places of a float value which can be 2013.43452 or 2392.2) ? Now I am getting exception like E`xception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,846.40"`.

Comment: Why do you need those decimal places? `b` would also be just `1846.4` and that formatting+parsing is just odd and totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the direct problem causing the NFE is the thousand separators in the string, not the number of decimal places. You have both a `','` and a `'.'` in the string, and `parseFloat` doesn't like that.

Note, however, that you can't fix the number of decimal places in a `float` value - it is entirely a formatting issue. Specifically, trailing `0`'s have no significance in floating point values, thus will not be shown by default. You need to format the value according to your wishes at the point of output (when converting it into a displayable `String` e.g. by using `DecimalFormat` as you did above).

Comment: I want to set 2 decimal place of the a float. any way to set incoming value?

Comment: @PTY, you can't do it the way you are trying to - see my update.

Comment: yes. it would be the better way. I shouldn't try to set the decimal place and should play with value when it needs to display.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you simply want to round to two decimal places.

Number format and mucking around with strings isn't where you want to go.

Try this:

```
float b = Math.round(a * 100)/100.0f;
```

Comment: Took the liberty of changing the divisor so you get a `float` with floating point division instead of `long` with integer division.

Comment: plus one. I will use it next time. but now I just plan to play with the value when it needs to display.

Comment: This technique does not work, with over 90% unreliability. And 'number format and mucking around with strings' is *exactly* where he wants to go, or else use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

To get your formatting + parsing to work, just use `df` again:

```
float b = df.parse( df.format(a));
```

However, I still don't see any sense in that. You *can't* define the number of decimal places in a floating point number. 1846.40 is the same as 1846.4 or 1846.400, the trailing zeros are totally irrelevant.

Those digits come into play when you have output, e.g. writing the number to a string. But there are other facilities to do that, e.g. a string format pattern.

If you need to restrict the number of fraction digits internally use `BigDecimal` where you can set the scale and thus define the number of fraction digits it represents.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to set decimal places for a float

There isn't one. Floats don't *have* decimal places. They have binary places.

If you want decimal places you have to use a decimal radix, either a `BigDecimal` or the result of `DecimalFormat.format()`.